# Make the width and height of a div the same on all resolutions(only desktops, not mobile)

Tags: html, css

I'm currently developing a new secure and encrypted social network and I'm stuck now.
I never thought about how my website will look on other desktops and laptops(not mobiles). The problem is I defined all element sizes with px.
I want that my website looks on other machines exactly with same proportions.

Any ideas?

P.s. I don't want to use %

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use `vh` and `vw`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The topic of size units is a broad one you should read up on.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length

You have a few options. One, you can use media-queries to greatly change your site's layout based on a few resolution ranges.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries

Two, you can change almost all your uses of `px` to one of the other size units. `em` can be used to base any size/distance on the current font size, and `vh/vw` can be used to base sizes on the current resolution. (eg, `width: 100vw` will be as wide as the screen)

Responsive layout usually involves using several of these techniques together. My prediction is that if you want the same proportion on any device, you'll likely want to base all distances on `em`, and set a different `font-size` at the root based on a media query. That said, it's not always wrong to allow all devices to have different sizes because of their resolution; normally smaller/larger devices have ways of adjusting because of that. For instance, few sites are unusable simply because Apple makes super-high-resolution monitors for OS X and Safari.

If you don't have other laptops on hand, many browsers can imitate another device, or another device's resolution, using their F12 Developer Tools.